# Passing an object to a method CPP C++

Tags: c++

I'm still learning C++ so go easy on me.
Is there a way I can pass an object to a method without specifying an object? I'm probably butchering the terms so ill show code.

```
class Student
{private:
    std::string Name;
    float GPA;
    char Sex;
    int Absentee;
    int *Data ;
public:
    std::string GetName();
    float GetGPA();
    char GetSex();
    int GetAbsentee();
    void SetData(int);
    int GetData();
    int *GetDataAddr();

    //Methods
    void DisplayStudent(Student);

void Student::DisplayStudent(Student Stud)
{
    std::cout << "___________________________________" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name     :" << Stud.GetName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GPA      :" << Stud.GetGPA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sex      :" << Stud.GetSex() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Absentee :" << Stud.GetAbsentee() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Data     :" << Stud.GetData() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Data Add :" << Stud.GetDataAddr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "___________________________________" << std::endl;
}



int main() {

    
    Student Spike("Spike", 3.9f, 'M', 43,55);
    * Compiles fine: Spike.DisplayStudent(Spike);
    * DOSNT Compile: Student DisplayStudent(Spike);
    * C++ a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object*
    return 0;

}
```

So the question I have is at least with this method, why do I need to specify or rather, what is the purpose of "Spike" in "Spike.DisplayStudent(.....)"? Student::Display(.....) makes far more sense to me.

Comment: You should have a constructor that sets the variables to your parameters.  You don't have one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually do have one I just ripped it out for the sake of visibility

Comment: _"what is the purpose of "Spike" in "Spike.DisplayStudent(.....)"?_" - It could have a purpose if `DisplayStudent` was `static` _or_ that there is some operation that needs _two_ students (`*this` and the `Student` argument).

Comment: Objects know themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Student::DisplayStudent` is designed to display information for the student who is represented by that class instance, you don't need to pass `Student Stud` at all, just use member variables.

If however it is designed to display info for ANY student - you can make it a `static` member, or a free-standing function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the member function `DisplayStudent` to display the information for the very instance of `Student` on which the function is called, you do not need to pass a `Student` as an argument.

```cpp
class Student {
public:
    // The getter methods should be `const`, since calling them does not change
    // the `Student`:
    const std::string& GetName() const; // return a `const&` to avoid unecessary copying
    void DisplayStudent() const;        // No `Student` argument, like in `GetName()`
    // ...
};

void Student::DisplayStudent() const {
    std::cout << "___________________________________\n"
                 "Name     :" << GetName() << "\n"
                 "GPA      :" << GetGPA() << "\n"
                 "Sex      :" << GetSex() << "\n"
                 "Absentee :" << GetAbsentee() << "\n"
                 "Data     :" << GetData() << "\n"
                 "Data Add :" << GetDataAddr() << "\n"
                 "___________________________________\n";
}
```

You also do not need to call *getter* methods in `DisplayStudent()` since you have access to the `private` member variables and do not need to do any calculations before returning the result.

Usage example (if the appropriate constructor exists as you've indicated):

```cpp
int main() {
    Student Spike("Spike", 3.9f, 'M', 43,55);
    Spike.DisplayStudent(); // no instance passed as an argument
}
```